# Passing JSX elements to a function requires manual keys to be present?

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I'm trying to pass a React JSX element to a function, so that this element can be displayed as part of a React component, like in the following example:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { action, observable } from 'mobx'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

export class OverlayStore {
  @observable activePopup = null

  @action
  setPopup(element) {
    this.activePopup = element
  }
}

@observer
export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{overlayStore.activePopup}</div>
  }
}

const overlayStore = new OverlayStore()
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))

overlayStore.setPopup(
  <p>
    Long<br key="1" />
    Text<br key="2" />
    <a href="/link" key="3">
      Link
    </a>
  </p>
)
```

[image: Edit 4qm2p107r7]

My problem is that I receive a key error unless I add the manual key values as seen in the code.

Why is this required? This is not a for each loop or a map which would require keys. Actually, the passed JSX can be considered static, thus it shouldn't need keys at all. Is it possible to tell React to consider an element as static and don't look for keys?

Answer (score -1):

The code posted is attaching items outside of the `render` method. This is not standard React, and I'm surprised the only error is around the keys.

By manually injecting DOM, this bypasses the virtual DOM and won't be part of the React reconciliation process.

**UPDATE**

This answer is incorrect. The change to the mobx observable triggers a re-render, so this doesn't happen outside of the React component lifecycle.

Comment: I'm not manually injecting DOM, I'm setting an element to a MobX observable.

Comment: Okay, but you're modifying items outside of the render method, even if it is valid JSX, it goes against the React paradigms

Comment: No I'm not modifying them outside.

Comment: My bad, I've just looked at this again, and the mobx observable is updated, which triggers a re-render of the App component. I've played around with the sandbox, and seems that when setting the popup, because the `div` has two children (p and textarea) it requires a key. I suppose what I find odd about this code, is it's storing JSX as state (mobx state in this case). Usually the best approach is to store data, and let your render method determine the JSX.